# SqlNode & PathNode in Hibernate

Tags: hibernate

With the following HQL

```
"select new Foo(f.id, f.date) from Foo f ..."
```

I get an ClassCastException:

```
java.lang.ClassCastException: org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.tree.SqlNode cannot be cast to org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.tree.PathNode
```

To my understanding, the error is due to an incorrect HQL structure. I, however, can't tell what it is. Any class structure element will lead to this error?

Comment: what is `new Foo(f.id, f.date)` what do you wanted to do?

Comment: Show the full HQL please.

Comment: The error will disappear if I remove the class constructor portion. So, that part is a problem and nothing to do with the rest of HQL.

Comment: @vic Did you ever find a solution

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you want `select` clause to return Foo in the query result set.

What don't you ttry with fully qualified name of Foo

```
"select new com.name.Foo(f.id, f.date) from Foo f where f.id=2"
```

You need proper constructor to accept f.id and f.date

Comment: If there weren't a matched constructor, an error message would say a constructor can't be found.

Comment: @vic have you tried with fully qualified name of your class.